# "at risk" VS "at stake"

Tags: word-difference

> 1. He puts his administration **at risk** if he doesn't come through on these promises for reform.
> 2. He puts his administration **at stake**  if he doesn't come through on these promises for reform.

I am wondering whether at stake can replace at risk in this scenario to express the administration will be in danger of losing its credibility and been overturned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If something is "at *risk*" it is exposed to danger.

"At *stake*" has a slightly different inference. The expression is adapted from gambling terminology. Literally, a "stake" in gambling is the money gambled on an outcome.

Metaphorically, when something is spoken of as being "at stake" the inference is that, like a gamble, the particular thing has been deliberately placed at risk in the hope of "winning" rather than losing; whereas many things can be "at risk" for other reasons.

**Examples:**

> That building is at risk of falling down.

Nobody deliberately builds something knowing it has a chance of falling down. The risk here has likely come about through decay or some other causes over time. The risk to the building has not been deliberately brought about.

> He placed his job, his reputation and possibly his marriage at stake.

If someone deliberately places something at risk *hoping* that the risk will not materialise they are often said to have placed it "at stake", as if they have taken a gamble.

---

In your example, it sounds like *either* could be used, but I feel that they would need to be reworded slightly:

> He **has put** his administration at stake **on** these promises for reform coming through.

**or**

> He has staked his administration on these promises for reform coming through.

When you deliberately take a risk, the "stake" is there from the start, not only if you lose, so the conditional clause in your statement shouldn't really be there.

> **His** administration **is at risk** if he doesn't come through on these promises for reform.

Even if it was deliberate and placed at stake, the administration itself is *at risk* and so it is possible to use this word in this way with the conditional clause..